# SAML token authentication in .net core with ws fed

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, saml, ws-federation

We are trying to authenticate a SAML token in a .net core application which is configured to use wsfed authentication.

We had similar problem in our previous project that was on .net framework.we had to implement a customauthentication module and override the existing signinresponse message as shown below

```
if (authorizationHeader.StartsWith(SAML_SCHEME))
                tokenStartIndex = SAML_SCHEME.Length;
            else if (authorizationHeader.StartsWith(SAML2_SCHEME))
                tokenStartIndex = SAML2_SCHEME.Length;

            var encodedBase64Token = authorizationHeader.Substring(tokenStartIndex);
            var data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedBase64Token);
            var decodedToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

            return new SignInResponseMessage(request.Url, decodedToken);
```

Is there any way we can implement something similar in .net core as well. Thanks in advance.

Edit: For the signinresponse message. Please find the below link that we used as reference

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/842519/Verify-ADFS-SAML-token-on-ASP-NET-service

Answer (score 0):

> What is `SignInResponseMessage` in your code?

In .net core, the configuration of ws fed authentication is implemented through **middleware** instead of moudle.

And you don't need to use a custom method, you only need to register this service in the **ConfigureServices** method of **startup.cs**:

```
   .AddWsFederation(options =>
     {
         options.Wtrealm = Configuration["wsfed:realm"];
         options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["wsfed:metadata"];
     })
```

More details, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-ws-federation-without-aspnet-core-identity).

Comment: we are actually using the same middleware to authenticate the user but this apparently doesn't support the SAML token coming from different application (SAML "authentication token"). We need a way to override the middle configuration to allow saml token to authenticate the users dynamically.  That is if the token is SAML from different application it should accept the SAML token and parse the user information from it and authenticate, else it should be using the default wsfed configuration